# Why does reinterperet cast work on pointers and static doesn't

Tags: c++

I'm learning about type casting and finding it pretty tough to understand it.
So from what I've learned. You cannot static cast pointers of one type to another. I don't know exactly why. Because you can static cast an int to a char which has there own address in memory so its super confusing me as to why you cannot do the same with pointers.

So with reinterpret cast. You can convert a pointer type to another pointer type. I think?

So a few questions i have are. You can convert non pointer variables with  a static cast.

And You can cast pointers types to different pointer types using reinterpret?

Below are some examples of stuff I'm struggling on.

```
<int *>something // what is the * inside of the <int> meaning? 

// i know what the previous *<int> means to deference.

// So if i have this does this mean I'm casting something into a char pointer
// and storing the cast inside of ptr?

char* ptr = static_cast<char *>something 

//With reinterpret cast i can cast from another type like this 

int x = 9;
int* ptr = {&x};

char* nowchar = reinterpret_cast<char *>&x

// the above is fine? 

//But i cannot do the same with static

int x = 8;
int* ptr = {&x};

char* nowchar = static_cast<char*>&x;
```

Can you explain why i cannot use static on a pointer, and why reinterpret_cast works

Comment: Well, it's same reason why automobiles can't fly and airplanes can't drive on highways. Each one is designed for different things.

Comment: could you explain some more as to why thanks

Comment: Broadly `static_cast<>` is for normal casting. What's normal? So casting a `double` to an `int` is a normal thing to be doing. That's not to say it is 100% safe because the value may be out of range but moving between arithmetic types is 'normal' within a type system. Now casting a pointer to a char* is always valid because on of the roles of `char` is to be byte and in C++ it's always valid to go to 'machine level' and treat memory as a sequence of bytes. But(!) it is an exercise in going round the type system so isn't in the set of 'type system condoned' static-casts!

Comment: Okay i get you thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking this one question at a time:

`<int *>something // what is the * inside of the <int> meaning?`

When you are casting, what you put in the angle brackets is the *type*, `int*` (or `int *`) is a pointer to an integer. This is often confusing for those new to C++ because you also use the `*` operator to dereference a pointer, but in this context it denotes that the type is a pointer to an `int` and not an `int`.

```
// So if i have this does this mean I'm casting something into a char pointer
// and storing the cast inside of ptr?

char* ptr = static_cast<char *>something
```

Yes, the only case I'm aware of where this will work is if you are casting from / to a `void*` or if you are casting from a base class to a derived class, e.g.:

```
class Something{};
class SomethingElse : public Something{};

...

Something* something = new Something();
SomethingElse* ptr = static_cast<SomethingElse *>(something);
```

In this case, you are correct that you are casting the pointer to the instance of `Something` into a pointer for the derived class `SomethingElse`.

```
//With reinterpret cast i can cast from another type like this 

int x = 9;
int* ptr = {&x};

char* nowchar = reinterpret_cast<char *>(&x);

// the above is fine? 

//But i cannot do the same with static

int x = 8;
int* ptr = {&x};

char* nowchar = static_cast<char*>(&x);
```

In C++, static_cast is only used for a few (mostly) well-defined conversions. There is no well-defined conversion from a pointer to an `int` to a pointer to a `char`. Considering that neither the size (number of bits) of `char` nor `int` are specified, this makes sense. What does the compiler do if you are trying to cast a 16-bit `int` to an 8-bit `char`? In this case, what you need to do is *reinterpret* the `int` pointer to a `char` pointer; hence why you need to use a `reinterpret_cast` instead. Specifically, this will tell the compiler that it is allowed to reinterpret the underlying bit pattern of the data however it sees fit.